# how to catch the specific ID which causes error in a bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, try-catch

I have a code block with INSERT statement with many logic applied and at few minutes later it gets failed due to any others insert error like 'truncation errors' and so. And so the insert get failed and raises an error as I mentioned in catch block, but I need to know which specific ID causes that error. Is that possible to get that ID? 
below is my sample code block

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT INTO MyTable (fieldA, fieldB,.....)
        SELECT (fieldA, fieldB,.....)
        FROM <many joins from other tables>

    COMMIT TRAN

END TRY 

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE()
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

Here in that CATCH block can we get the fieldA value along with ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE() if inserts failed?

Or is there any other way to see that specific fieldA value which causes error?
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems that some of your data is getting truncated during the insert.  It would help for you to show us some sample data, and possibly the real query, so that we may have a better idea about what is going on here.

Comment: you can use the same select statement before your insert statment and assign fieldA into a variable, then you can select the value of the variable in the catch block

Comment: I'll suggest to check all table and match the columns have the same length and datatype.

Comment: @ShikharArora That is not possible as he is not looping through the data, he is fetching data from other table and inserting it as a bulk in new table.

Comment: Yes yeou is correct, I'm not looping through the data so I can't assign it to a variable.  @Yeou I checked it but there are million of rows processing and its hard to find which one causes trouble.

Comment: you can still do your select without the `insert` so you can inspect the data you want to insert

Comment: SQL Server  doesn't provide any way to do this, you need to clean the data-detect invalid values- in the source table in advance.

Comment: @Yeou my mistake,got it.

Comment: @Mar1009 First you need to find the column that has a larger length than target column. then you can just do a query on it to find the column having larger text. `select * from table where len(col1) > 20`. this way you can find rows that have invalid text.

Comment: Thanks Yeou, this is final option I too thought of, just wanted to know if there is any other. thanks for all the comments

Comment: Is it fine if you can get the inserted ones so can find find errored ones from that ?

Comment: @HadiArdebili if there is error occurs then my transaction will be roll backed so there will be no data inserted actually right? so i'm not clear what you proposing, please elborate

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this might work :

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE (id bigint)
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE @ids TABLE (id bigint)
    INSERT INTO b.tbl
    OUTPUT Inserted.ID INTO @ids(id)
    select       f1,f2,f3 from b.tbl
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY 

BEGIN CATCH
    select * from @ids
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE()
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```